# iis 7.5 application pool memory usage

Tags: web-applications, memory-management, iis-7.5

I have configured and deployed an identical web application to 2 separate servers.

- Server1: Virtual Server, windows 2008
  r2 enterprise edition, 1GB ram.
- Server2: Virtual Server, windows 2008
  r2 data center edition, 4GB ram.
- When the web application is started on Server1 it acquires approximately 11MB of ram.
- When the web application is started on Server2 it acquires approximately 113MB of ram.

All setup of both servers was scripted so I believe that I have identical iis configuration on both servers.

Identical web application dll's have been deployed to Server1 and Server2.

Any ideas where I should start looking to try and identify why I need approximately x10 times the memory on server2 to run the same web application?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're not really comparing like with like (OS and physical memory).

The worker process on the server with more memory is probably being more aggressive at reserving memory upon startup because there's more available.